# Attribute called 'description' causes crash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I just started playing with Core Data.

I created an entity called **Task** with a property called **Description**. I opened Interface Builder and I added **Core Data Entity** view.

Picked my entity, property and tried to build the application. After clicking on "Add" button it crashed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

After I've renamed this attribute to 'desc' it works fine.

Can anyone explain me why is this happening? Is 'description' some kind of reserved word in Core Data or something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`description` is ann Objective-C property used for debugging and goes all the way down to Core Foundation, which has a corresponding `CFDescription` function. You should just name that property something else.

Comment: More Cocoa than Objective-C, but yeah.

Comment: It's method of NSObject. All classes that inherit from NSObject (which is virtually all) inherit the method. It produces a textual description of the object for debugging purposes. When you log an object with `NSLog(@"%@",anObject)` it calls the description method.

Comment: I wrote Cocoa at first then edited it to Objective-C so I should have left it as it was.

Comment: As an additional comment to the OP, the compiler ***warns*** you that this is a reserved word.  Never ever ignore warnings in Objective-C.

Comment: I missed the warning :-(. Is there a list of reserved words that I can't use as property names?

Answer (score 6):

It's a method with a particular purpose in Cocoa, and Core Data dislikes it being overridden. [More here.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW7)